# Copiar e invertir vectores de tipo string en Java

Tags: java, vectores

Tengo un ejercicio que no logro completar: "Se necesita un vector que permita cargar por teclado el nombre de 10 animales. A partir de esta carga, se desea otro vector que copie los mismos nombres pero en el orden inverso, es decir, si los nombres son: perro, gato, lagartija, el nuevo vector debe contener: lagartija, gato, perro. Una vez realizado el cambio, mostrar por pantalla ambos vectores para compararlos". Hice el siguiente código pero  me tira error:

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String [] animales = new String[10];
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       System.out.print("ingrese los animales: " + i);
       animales[i] = sc.next();
       }
       String [] animales2 = new String[animales.length];
    System.arraycopy(animales, 0, animales2, 0, animales.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < animales2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(animales[-i]);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el error que te tira

Comment: Por cierto tu código no hace lo que pide el ejercicio. No estás invirtiendo el vector `animales2`, solo lo estás imprimiendo al revés en la pantalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrias agregar los datos de `animales` a `animales2` con ciclo for reverso

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Prueba {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String [] animales = new String[10];
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       System.out.println("ingrese los animales: " + (i+1));
       animales[i] = sc.next();
       }

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animales));

       String [] animales2 = new String[animales.length];

       int j=0;
   // Se tomaran los datos de animales desde el ultimo al primero indice
   // y seran agregados a animales2 desde el primero hasta el ultimo indice
        for (int i = animales.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
         animales2[i]=animales[j];
         j++;
      }

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animales2));
    }
    }
```